# WPF, TextBox validation and binding just one item from a List<string>

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding

I'm trying to refactor my code. At the moment, my Validator class possesses 10 different strings, each of which represents the content of a different TextBox.

Here a snippet of my C# code (which is working without any issue):

```
// The string contained in the TextBox.
private string MasterPointName => null;

// Other strings...
....

// The validator.
public string this[string columnName]
{
    string result = null;

    get
    {
        switch (columnName)
        {
            case "MasterPointName":
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.MasterPointName))
            {
                result = "This field must not be left empty!";
            }

            break;

            // Other case statements...
            ...
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And this is the XAML for one of the aforementioned TextBoxes:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbMaster" Validation.Error="ValidationError" Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=MasterPointName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />
```

Now I'd like to put all of my strings in a `List<string>` and refer to the list items in my case statements:

```
private readonly List<string> points = new List<string>
                          {
                              "masterPointName",
                              ...
                          };

// The validator.
public string this[string columnName]
{
    string result = null;

    get
    {
        switch (columnName)
        {
            case "masterPointName":
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.points[0]))
            {
                result = "This field must not be left empty!";
            }

            break;

            // Other case statements...
            ...
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Updated XAML (using `Path=points[0]`):

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbMaster" Validation.Error="ValidationError" Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=points[0], ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />
```

I thought it would had worked, referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18659756/4938112) answer, but I'm probably missing something. Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible? Does it even make any sense?

Comment: You can only bind on properties. Make your List a property

Comment: Did you try making it a `public ObservableCollection Points{ get; set; }`?

Comment: @Freggar, the answer I've linked in my question says otherwise. May I ask for some more insights, please? Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelHufnagel, may I ask for a code snippet that can show me how to use that? Thanks.

Comment: I think there is some miscommunication. I don't see how the answer says that you can bind on normal Fields? I just meant that you have to declare your List as `public List<string> points {get; set;}` or otherwise WPF cannot do something like `{Binding points[0]}`

Comment: E.g. you cannot bind on something like `private string MasterPoint;` and neither can you bind on something like `private List<string> points;`

Comment: Oh, ok. And what about the inizialitation of `point`? Should I do that with the `set` in the constructor? Sorry, but I'm pretty new to C# and I'm still struggling with some concepts.

Comment: Nah, you just need to add the additional `{get;}`. This should do it `public List<string> points {get;} = new List<string>
                          {
                              "masterPointName",
                              ...
                          };`

Comment: Something is moving, but I still can't make that work: now my TextBox contains the string I've declared in my list, which is not obviously what I'm trying to achieve.