# C# MVVM indexing a collection

Tags: c#, indexing, mvvm

I have a Model, RecipeType, which contains an ObservableCollection of components:

```
public class RecipeType
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ComponentType> Components { get; set; }
}
public class ComponentType
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public float Density { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have 2 Recipes listed, each pointing to one of the two different Components.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Density[0], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Density[1], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

How do I set up the getter, setter for these parameters? How do I know which one to update?

```
public string Density[index] //I know this is not correct, but it represents what i am trying to do
    {
        get { return RecipeConnection.Components[0].Density.ToString(); }
        set { value; }
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659667/wpf-how-to-bind-to-only-one-item-in-a-collection-not-using-itemscontrol-since

Comment: You need to have a where (and/or OrderBy) to filter items.  SQL Server is multiple-threaded and queries do no return data in the same order every time.  So you need to filter data so you update the correct object(s).  With event you have to use the parameters in the event method to get a link back to the actual source.