# Bind to specific item in collection without indexer

Tags: wpf, data-binding, hashset

I am using an EF5 datamodel, in which the related entities are collected into a HashSet. I want to bind an element to the first related entity in the HashSet. I've seen answers on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715478/wpf-binding-to-specific-items-in-collection) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659667/wpf-how-to-bind-to-only-one-item-in-a-collection-not-using-itemscontrol-since)) which suggest using the following:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedValueBinding="{Binding LeadSteps[0].NewZoneID}"/>
```

but this relies on the collection having an indexer, which HashSet doesn't have.

(If this cannot be done, I can create a property in a partial class to the entity, and bind to that.)

How can I bind to the n-th item in a collection when the collection doesn't implement an integral indexer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's an old question, but i also ran into just the same problem and found a solution i thought to share.

What worked for me was changing the declaration of the referencing member from:

```
public virtual ICollection<MyType> MyVarName { get; set; }
```

to:

```
public virtual IList<MyType> MyVarName { get; set; }
```

After this change, the collection items were accessible with the normal accessor:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyVarName[0].MyMemberName}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to rethink this whole situation. A `HashSet` is a 'set' of unique items, not a collection. A set is simply meant to maintain a group of members and to enable you to check whether a particular item is a member or not... there's no indexing because there is no order amongst the set items.

Although you can call the `Enumerable.ElementAt<TSource>` method on a `HashSet`, you *cannot* guarantee that it will return the same element when providing the same input value to the method. Most importantly, if the order of items in the `HashSet` is important to you, then you should be using a collection instead.

However, if you choose to ignore this advise, this is how you could achieve your requirement... just define a wrapper property for your single `HashSet` value... you could try something like this:

```
public YourHashSetDataType Hash
{
    get { return LeadSteps.ElementAt(0).NewZoneID; }
    set { LeadSteps.ElementAt(0).NewZoneID = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Hash"); }
}
```