# Binding to property of first item in related (detail) collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Similar to [WPF: How to bind to only one item in a collection, not using ItemsControl since I don't want to display all of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659667/wpf-how-to-bind-to-only-one-item-in-a-collection-not-using-itemscontrol-since?lq=1), except the collection is related to the main binding item.  All the data come in via EntityFramework.  As with the linked question, the xaml explains it best:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding CurrentCustomer}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Total Orders:" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Orders.Count}" />
  </StackPanel >

  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="First Order:" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Orders.First.OrderDate}" />
  </StackPanel >
</StackPanel>
```

As you can see, I guessed that since I could get a count of the related orders using 'Orders.Count', I tried to utilise the same linq syntax to try to retrieve Orders.First (I also tried Orders.FirstOrDefault), but this doesn't work.

Looking at the linked question, I tried [Sheridan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249281/sheridan)'s '[]' syntax, but Orders[0].OrderDate give an output error of:  `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '[]' property not found on 'object' ''HashSet'1' (HashCode=37425772)'. BindingExpression:Path=Orders[0].OrderDate; DataItem='Customer_<BigLongIdentityString>' (HashCode=21972018); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')`.

Looking at the msdn article he linked to, I tried wrapping the expression in brackets (as per attached properties) and using slashes (as for when the source is a collection).  Not unexpectedly, these failed too.

Can someone show me how I get to the property of the first item in a related collection?

Comment: First is an extension method i.e. `Orders.First().OrderDate` ?

Comment: @StuartLC good idea, but no.  Same error msg: `BindingExpression path error: 'First()' property not found on 'object'`

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I didn't see that one.  I don't know how to change the HashSet to a Collection as it's all EF magic (I too generally stick to ObservableCollection), but that answer plus your first comment looks like the answer to my question: make a property in the VM that retrieves the Order with the earliest date from the HashSet.  Do you want to answerify your comments and I'll accept?

Comment: @mcalex All done; take a look at my edit that talks about the T4 templates for EF code generation.

Comment: I remember reading that a while back (now you've reminded me).  I think there should be a suggestion made by the EF wizard when generating models to ask if you want WPF bindable models which takes care of these details.  Thank you, problem solved :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If possible, you can always add a new property to your model that exposes the first item:

```
public Order FirstItem 
{ 
    get { return this.Orders.First(); }
}
```

Then, you can just bind to that new property.

Also, [this answer is highly relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21554100/656243). A hashset may not be a good fit, here. There's no indexer. I generally stick to ObservableCollections.

Also, with regard to EF generation compatible with databinding, take a look at [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx). Read the section called

> Updating code generation for data binding

You can mess with the T4 template and per the article,

> Find and replace the first occurrence of “HashSet” with
>   “ObservableCollection”.

Happy WPF'ing.