# In Caliburn Micro How to bind an element in view to a member of collection in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, caliburn.micro

I have a view that displays a number of tiles in a fixed layout.  Let's say there are 5 tiles for the purposes of this discussion.

In my ViewModel I have a List of value objects and I would like the tiles in the View to bind to these TileVO objects.  The length of this list may be greater or less than 5.

I would like to be able to manually tell each Tile in the View to bind to a specific index in the List in the ViewModel.

The following example is bogus syntax, but it basically represents what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
<Tile Content="{Binding Path=TileVOs[1].Content}"/>
```

Is there a  way to tell Caliburn Micro to bind a view element to a specific index in a collection in the ViewModel?

or,

Is there a way to use a function or expression to provide the target of the binding?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715478/wpf-binding-to-specific-items-in-collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently you can use that syntax after all.  It just wasn't working for me because my VO's fields were simple variables and not properties with getters and setters.